# How to Handle Service Reference Errors?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, service-reference

I have a WCF service hosted on a server, but whenever internet connection fails i'm getting error **System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException**. Even though I tried to handle that in completed method, error pops up in Reference Page Method.

Erros is because of Server is not found..! But there should be a way to handle this..!

How do I restrict and handle this error? Otherwise I have to remove Services..! Is There any Other way to do or handle this?

Comment: can you share you code sample?

Comment: It sounds like the client is getting that message.  If so, I suggest catching the error in a try-catch block on the client.  There's no other way to do that that I can think of - if the server is not there, it's not there.  You may need to check the inner exception(s) to get the actual root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited the reference.cs page with try and catch for the receiving method of service.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle this by putting proper Exception handling and Exception class for that is  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you tried to connect the Windows phone 8 emulator to the `localhost` WCF service?

This won't work because the emulator is in a virtual machine but there are steps to fix it:

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

For [more](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-US/61f1060f-846e-4e7d-b8ff-c2956e0a8677/visual-studio-2012-windows-phone-8-wcf-systemservicemodelcommunicationexception)

Comment: Actually my problem is when the internet does not work...! there are chances when mobile phone does not get the best reception or nothing at all. when that happens, program returns an exception...! I know what you mean. I had that Problem because of that I switched to Mobile Devices instead of Emulator